# The positive element in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The following is a theorem of Conway's Functional Analysis: [image]

for the proof ($c\to a$), I think we can say: for $\lambda\in \sigma(a)\subset \Bbb R$, there is a character $h:C(\sigma(a))\to\Bbb C$ such that $\lambda=h(a)=|h(x)|^2$, so $\lambda\geq 0$ and $\sigma(a)\subset [0,\infty)$.

I think it's easier than Conway's way, but I'm not sure that it's correct or not. Please check it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you assumed that $x$ is normal?

Comment: @T.A.E. : no, x is not normal. just a is self-adjoint and I think it's sufficient. Isn't it?

Comment: If $x$ is not normal, then the $C^{\star}$ algebra containing $x, x^{\star}$ is not commutative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't correct, because you are trying to use "$|h(x)|$" without it having been defined.